# Preserve original order if numeric value is equal in coreutils sort?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, gnu-coreutils

Consider this snippet:

```
echo '7 a
3 c
3 b
2 first
2 second
2 third
2 fourth
2 fifth
9 d
2 sixth
' | sort -n -k 1
```

It gives an output of:

```
2 fifth
2 first
2 fourth
2 second
2 sixth
2 third
3 b
3 c
7 a
9 d
```

While the list is correctly ordered numerically keyed by first character, also for those values which are contiguous and equal, the original order has been shuffled. I would like to obtain:

```
2 first
2 second
2 third
2 fourth
2 fifth
2 sixth
3 c
3 b
7 a
9 d
```

Is this possible to do with `sort`? If not, what would be the easiest way to achieve this kind of sorting using shell tools?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the `-s` (stable sort) flag, this disables last-resort comparison

```
echo '7 a
3 c
3 b
2 first
2 second
2 third
2 fourth
2 fifth
9 d
2 sixth
' | sort  -k 1,1n -s

2 first
2 second
2 third
2 fourth
2 fifth
2 sixth
3 c
3 b
7 a
9 d
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @1_CR - I actually did notice the "last-resort comparison" wording in the manpage, because I thought it sounded strange - and not once did it occur to me that it is related to this! Appreciate the snippet - cheers!

Comment: In addition to `-s`, you need to specify your key as `-k 1,1` because a `KEYDEF  is  F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]  for  start and stop position` ... `and the stop position defaults to the line's end`. So if you specify `-k 1`, the whole string will be used for sorting. You can use `--debug` to see for each line which part was used for sorting.

Comment: @benediktkoppel, indeed. Fixes

Answer (score 2):

Add line numbers with `nl`, pipe to `sort -k2,1` to use the line numbers as the secondary key, then cut the numbers off with `cut`. Or use `sort -s`. :p

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Amadan - at first, I was like "What?"; and then I realized it was a clever ruse `:)` Appreciate the humor - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a "stable" sort.  Try the sort `-s` option (or better yet, check the man page on your system).

Comment: Many thanks for that jdigital - you were first, but I appreciated the snipped in @1_CR 's answer more; I checked the manpage, but I couldn't tell that "disabling last-resort comparison" is related to this. Cheers!